# How to use Objective-C sources' ExplicitInit class?

Tags: c++, objective-c

In the Objc source code, I found the following code. What is the meaning of this code and how to understand it?

objc/Project Headers/DenseMapExtras.h line:38

```
template <typename Type>
class ExplicitInit {
    alignas(Type) uint8_t _storage[sizeof(Type)];

public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    void init(Ts &&... Args) {
        new (_storage) Type(std::forward<Ts>(Args)...);
    }

    Type &get() {
        return *reinterpret_cast<Type *>(_storage);
    }
};
```

Below is my test code:

```
class MyC{
public:
    long l1;
    long l2;
    MyC(long _l1, long _l2){
        l1 = _l1;
        l2 = _l2;
    }
};
```

```
int main(){
    MyExplicitInit<MyC> e1 {};
    e1.init();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler prompts the following error:
[image]

Comment: *What is the meaning of this code and how to understand it?* -- C++ is one of the most difficult languages to learn.  You cannot learn it by cherry-picking code you find somewhere and attempting to understand it.  What do you know about forwarding arguments?  Placement-new? Alignment?  You will not get answers without first understanding C++ beyond the beginner stage (and in any event, best answered by good C++ books).

Comment: Simpler. How should the parameters be filled in here?

Comment: @Crazs Refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Objc source code, I found the following code. What is the
> meaning of this code and how to understand it?

To me it looks like a kind-of-factory which can be used as an alternative to the **Construct On First Use Idiom**. An instantiated class here represents a storage for an instance you can initialise and request when needed. As far as I understand it's not supposed to be used for local variables (it doesn't make much sense, despite being technically possible) and this is also [suggested by the comments of code section with the said class template](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-818.2/runtime/DenseMapExtras.h.auto.html):

> ```
> // We cannot use a C++ static initializer to initialize certain globals because
> // libc calls us before our C++ initializers run. We also don't want a global
> // pointer to some globals because of the extra indirection.
> //
> // ExplicitInit / LazyInit wrap doing it the hard way
> ```

---

For the error you are experiencing:

> No matching `operator new` function for non-allocating placement new expression;
> include `<new>`

Assuming that you just added that piece of code somewhere in your own sources, the problem here is that you didn't include the `<new>` header. As simple as that - the error just says that you need to add `#include <new>` since so-called **placement new** is not part of the "default" C++, it's an overloaded operator [declared in this header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Second, your `init` function expects arguments that matches one of the existing (non-aggregate) constructors of the given class, so you are expected to pass arguments which are either match the constructor parameters or can be implicitly converted to them: `e1.init(1l, 2l)`

A complete example looks something like this:

```
#include <_types/_uint8_t.h>
#include <new>

namespace objc {

    template <typename Type>
    class ExplicitInit {
        alignas(Type) uint8_t _storage[sizeof(Type)];

    public:
        template <typename... Ts>
        void init(Ts &&... Args) {
            new (_storage) Type(std::forward<Ts>(Args)...);
        }

        Type &get() {
            return *reinterpret_cast<Type *>(_storage);
        }
    };

};

struct sample_struct {
    long l1, l2;
    
    sample_struct(long _l1, long _l2): l1{_l1}, l2{_l2} {}
};

sample_struct& getInstance(bool should_init = false) {
    static objc::ExplicitInit<sample_struct> factory;
    if (should_init) {
        factory.init(1l, 2l);
    }
    return factory.get();
}
```

Comment: you're great！I added `#include <new>` and it worked.